# Too many open files when using django-eventstream

Tags: django, django-channels

We are using `django-eventstream` for sending out events to clients. You can think of our workflow to be celery like use case but a very simple one. Things were working flawlessly until we hit the '`too many open files`' error (`Redhat 7.4`). We tracked which processes are opening the files using '`lsof`' and found python was shooting several threads which loaded the required libraries (mostly .so files). We are using `gunicorn` as our server which spawns `uvicorn` workers. Tried to fall back to '`runserver`', but faced the same issue.

On trying out the '`time`' and '`chat`' examples, we saw the same behavior. On every refresh of the page (same machine, same browser, same tab) a new thread is spawned and '`lsof`' lists an increment of about 2k files on every refresh of the page.

We tried to recreate the same issue on two other different machines with the same OS. Saw the same behavior, expect in 1 machine. This was a laptop with `4GB` of RAM and the rest are servers with `256GB` of RAM. Interestingly everything works absolutely fine in the laptop, but not in the servers. Maybe because of the relative sparsity of resources, OS is closing the files in the laptop but not in servers, which is causing the '`too many open files`' error?

Any idea how to resolve this issue?
Cheers!

Comment: Which component exactly returns this error? Is it triggered by `accept` or `open`?

Comment: I dug around a bit more and found out that for every request, ie, whenever I refresh the page, channels is creating a new session which then calls asgiref which calls asyncio to create a new thread and this new thread tries to open the required files which if done in large numbers, causes the 'too many open files' error.

The threads do not release the resources (the files) when I close the browser (firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Going ahead with the threads assumption, tried to limit number of threads by setting [ASGI_THREADS](https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/master/asgiref/sync.py) . The number of threads are now limited and thus the number of files too. I don't know what will happen if users > ASGI_THREADS will try to connect to the server. I guess now I need to read up on load balancing..